# The image on the site is getting closer on ios devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I had such a problem - on the desktop version, the image is displayed correctly. Exactly the same on android devices. But when you visit the site from an ios device, the image is very close and is not displayed as it should be. [click to see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW9hz.jpg)

**base_page.html**

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>{% block title %}Shop{% endblock title %}</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'img/favicon.png' %}"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,400;0,500;1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/meanmenu.min.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/responsive.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block container %}
    {% endblock container %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.countdown.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.meanmenu.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**page.html**

```
{% extends 'base_page.html' %} 
{% load static %} 

{% block title %} 
Shop
{% endblock title %} 

{% block container %} 
<div class="hero-area hero-bg">
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-9 offset-lg-2 text-center">
        <div class="hero-text">
          <div class="hero-text-tablecell">
            <p class="subtitle">Новое поступление</p>
            <h1>Предзаказ на клавиатуры Varmilo!</h1>
            <div class="hero-btns">
              <a href="{% url 'shop' %}" style="font-family:Roboto" class="boxed-btn">Каталог</a>
              <a href="{% url 'contact' %}" style="font-family:Roboto" class="bordered-btn">Контакты</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**main.css**

```
.hero-bg {
  background-image: url(../img/hero-bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.hero-area {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried contain instead of cover? I am curious if it could be a bug with background-attachment fixed as well. Seems that safari on iOS does not support background attachment https://caniuse.com/background-attachment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.